# Using a Let's Encrypt certificate on a HA Exchange DAG setup

Tags: exchange, ssl-certificate

I want to set up Let's Encrypt certificates on an on-prem Exchange setup. We have 2 Exchange servers, to my understanding these are configured as a DAG. At the moment, these have a single self-signed certificate that was manually installed on both servers.

As I understand, the certificates installed on both must be identical. I was looking at using Win-ACME to issue and renew the certificates with this command: `wacs.exe --source manual --host mail.example.com,webmail.example.com,autodiscover.example.com --store centralssl,certificatestore --certificatestore My --acl-fullcontrol "network service,administrators" --centralsslstore "C:\Central SSL" --installation iis,script --installationsiteid 1 --script "./Scripts/ImportExchange.v2.ps1" --scriptparameters "'{CertThumbprint}' 'IIS,SMTP,IMAP' 1 '{CacheFile}' '{CachePassword}' '{CertFriendlyName}'"` obtained from https://www.win-acme.com/manual/advanced-use/examples/exchange along with the Cloudflare DNS validation plugin.

As I understand, if I were to run this command on both servers, then on the day the certificate is up for renewal, one server will update first, store its new certificate in the `Central SSL` shared folder, but then there might be a few hours before the other server's renewal runs, during which they won't have matching certificates and there would be errors accessing email.

So, what is the correct way to handle Let's Encrypt certificate renewals?

Comment: To me you only need to renew the certificate on one server, then you can import the certificate to another server.

A thread from the Let's Encrypt community: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/wacs-how-it-works-importing-a-certificate-to-another-server/146991/3